# How to use boolean and/or condition to check for specific message

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

In Splunk query for searching text in log message is like `('condition 1' AND 'condition 2') OR ('condition 3')`. How can the same be achieved in Grafana Loki/LogQL?

I tried using below query in Grafana and it works for AND condition only

```
{k8s_container_name="container"}
 | json
 | line_format `{{.body}}`
 | json
 |= `condition 1`
 |= `condition 2`
```

Need suggestion how to add an OR block for condition 3 to above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general solution for `or` in stream selectors.

In this specific case, though, your goal can be accomplished with following query:

```
{k8s_container_name="container"}
 | json 
 | (body =~ `.*condition 1.*` and body =~ `.*condition 2.*`) or body =~ `.*condition 3.*`
 | line_format `{{.body}}`
 | json
```

Here instead of [line filter expressions](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#line-filter-expression) I use label filter. They can be grouped using `and` and `or`. For more information see documentation for [label filter expressions](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#label-filter-expression).

Note also, that `=~` and `!~` regex operators are fully anchored. That why all the `.*` needed in the expressions.

---

In more broader situation, as far as I know, you cannot apply `or` over `|=` operator. The best what can be done is using `|~` instead, with logic incorporated into regex.

In your example, expression will be like this:

```
|~ `condition1.*condition2|condition2.*condition1|condition3`
```

Comment: Thanks @markalex. I used this line filter exp. & it worked for me

`|~ "(condition1.*condition2)|(condition3)" `